# Very slow net communicate with Modbus-slave via TCP

Tags: linux, java, tcp, windows-10

I have a problem when communicate with MODBUS-slave device via MODBUS-TCP protocol on Linux. My Linux host and remote MODBUS-slave device linked directly by wire in one LAN. I have't access to MODBUS-slave device for diagnostic it. I read data from MODBUS device on Linux by few registers and all operation take a **27 seconds** time duration. But when i read the same data from same MODBUS-device on Windows operation takes about **20 milliseconds**. I wrote Java application for communicate with MODBUS with **j2mod-3.1.1** library. Version of Linux -

**Linux version 5.10.0-1045-generic (builder@build4) (gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.28)**

Version of Windows - **Microsoft Windows 10.0.19043**

I wrote down network dump by Wireshark for Windows and Linux: Windows
[dump from Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sd5l.png)

Linux [dump from Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGgGc.png)

Here is my TCP settings:

- Windows [Windows TCP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0pCI.png)
- Linux [Linux TCP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTEj2.png)

I see that when i communicate on Linux there is duplicated ACK messages and spurious retransmissions, but i don't understand why. Which TCP-setting on Linux is wrong?